# delete specific characters or words from string using pipes angular 11

Tags: angular

I am trying to delete characters in the string if it includes the characters.
so with this code it finds them once but if in the string they are used twice this code does not work. any ideas how to fix it?
P.S with loop does not work either already tried :(

```
 transform(value: string, ...args: unknown[]): any {
    let finalValue = value
  
      if (value.includes("&quot;")) {
        let lastValue = value.replace("&quot;", "")
        finalValue = lastValue
      }
      if (value.includes("&#039;")) {
        let lastValue = value.replace("&#039;", "")
        finalValue = lastValue
      }
    }
    return finalValue

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you have wrongly assigned your **finalValue variable**. When the execution comes in **2nd if block**, your finalValue is getting set with new value. You are not performing replace on the same variable on which you have already applied replace.

Secondly, either you need to add replace all or you need to add regex for replacing all the values.

Try below code :

```
transform(value: string, ...args: unknown[]) {
    let finalValue = value;
  
      if (finalValue.includes("&quot;")) {
        finalValue = finalValue.replace(/&quot;/g, "");
      }
      if (finalValue.includes("&#039;")) {
        finalValue = finalValue.replace(/&#039;/g, "");
      }
   return finalValue;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use replaceAll instead of replace
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll

Demo from site

```js
const p = 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. If the dog reacted, was it really lazy?';

console.log(p.replaceAll('dog', 'monkey'));
// expected output: "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy monkey. If the monkey reacted, was it really lazy?"


// global flag required when calling replaceAll with regex
const regex = /Dog/ig;
console.log(p.replaceAll(regex, 'ferret'));
// expected output: "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy ferret. If the ferret reacted, was it really lazy?"
```